# How to blacklist amdgpu?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel-modules

I would like to blacklist the amdgpu driver. I opened `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and added the following line:

```
blacklist amdgpu
```

Then I rebooted and ran `lsmod | grep amdgpu`:

```
$ lsmod | grep amdgpu
amdgpu               1564672  23
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 amdgpu
ttm                    98304  1 amdgpu
drm_kms_helper        151552  1 amdgpu
drm                   352256  11 amdgpu,ttm,drm_kms_helper
```

Why is the module still loading?

My desktop is running Kubuntu 17.04 and I have a Radeon R9 270X.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many modules are loaded from the initramfs, before the root filesystem is mounted. That means the initramfs contains its own copy of the modprobe configuration, so after editing, you need to update the initramfs:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

will do that. Note that only updates the one for the current kernel—you can specify additional arguments to update others (e.g., old kernels) as well.